# Erro PHP: "Can't use function return value in write context"

Tags: php

Está a aparecer-me este erro e não estou a conseguir perceber o porquê. A linha de código é a seguinte: `$matrix(0, $key)=$quantidade['id_product'];`

A função completa é a seguinte:

```
public function sumQuantidadesPorProduto() {

        $quantidades = $this->getAllQuantidadesLocais();

        $sum = 0;
        $matrix = array();
        foreach ($quantidades as $key => $quantidade) {
            $sum+=intval($quantidade['quantidade']);
            $matrix(0, $key) = $quantidade['id_product'];
            $matrix(1, $key) = $sum;
        }

        return $matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Você está cometendo um erro de syntaxe.

Para acessar arrays você deve utilizar `[` e não `(`.

Mude o seu código para ficar desta forma:

```
public function sumQuantidadesPorProduto() {

    $quantidades = $this->getAllQuantidadesLocais();

    $sum = 0;
    $matrix = array();
    foreach ($quantidades as $key => $quantidade) {
        $sum+=intval($quantidade['quantidade']);
        $matrix[0][$key] = $quantidade['id_product'];
        $matrix[1][$key] = $sum;
    }

    return $matrix;
}
```

Comment: Não me acredito que nem reparei nisso, e o problema é que tinha assim anteriormente ahah Muitas horas já a programar... obrigado, abraço!